# jQuery Expression equivalent in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, expression

What would be equivalent expression in AngularJS for jQuery's expression.

Expression

```
$('.className');
```

I believe this expression would serve equivalent as above in Angular

```
angular.element(document.querySelector(".className"))
```

Comment: I'm not an angular expert but a simple test shows as if you're right https://jsfiddle.net/z1kgde9u/

Comment: Did you run a simple test? did you look in angular docs?

Comment: @fatman yes, i ran the test. I want to access `offset().top;`. so was finding it in angular...  previously i was running `$('.className').offset.top`. what would be alternative for this expression?

Comment: well, that's not what you asked is it?

Comment: @fatman yes, due to this question, my original question was asked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AngularJS doesn't have a equivalent per say `$("stuffhere")` from jQuery. `angular.element()` simply takes a JavaScript DOM object or jQuery object, so what you posted is correct. Another example is below.

```
var result = document.getElementsByClassName("class1");
var wrappedAngularResult = angular.element(result);
```

or

```
var result = angular.element(".class1");
```

According to their docs, `angular.element` is an alias for jQuerys main function if available, if not it defaults to angulars built in lite version jqLite. [See here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element)

Answer (score 1):

Angular uses so called [jQuery lite](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element). It's a subset of jQuery. But if you include a full jQuery on your page then you can use `angular.element` the same way you use `$`.

From docs:

> If jQuery is available, angular.element is an alias for the jQuery function.